# Disambiguating the Sturm-Liouville form of a differential equation with two candidate eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

**Context**

There are some differential equations (like the one presented below) where there appears to be more than one way to rewrite the equation in Sturm-Liouville form. I am posting this question to attempt to understand how to resolve the ambiguity.

- Please bare in mind that there are more than one conventions for where positive and negative markers need to be in order for a differential equation to be considered to be in Sturm-Liouville form. This should not impede resolving this matter.

**Question**

Rewrite the equation below in Sturm-Liouville form and identify what symbol (either $\ell$ or $m$) is the eigenvalue.
\begin{align*}
\rho^2\,\frac{d^2 P_{\ell m}}{d\rho^2} + \rho \,\frac{d  P_{\ell m}}{d\rho } + \left(\ell^2\,\rho^2 - m^2 \right)P_{\ell m} &= 0.
\end{align*}

**My two answers**

From [2], I know that if both sides of
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2 P_{\ell m}}{d\rho^2} + \frac{1}{\rho}  \,\frac{d  P_{\ell m}}{d\rho } + \frac{\left(\ell^2\,\rho^2 - m^2 \right)}{\rho^2}\,P_{\ell m} &= 0.
\end{align*}
are multiplied by
\begin{align*}
p(x) 
&= 
\exp{\left(  \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \frac{1}{z} \,dz \right)}
= 
\exp{\left(     \ln{\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right)}   \right)}
= 
 \frac{\rho}{\rho_0},
\end{align*}
then the differential equation is put in the formally self-adjoint form
\begin{align*}
\frac{d }{d\rho }\left( \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\frac{d  P_{\ell m}}{d\rho }\right)
+ 
 \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\frac{\left(\ell^2\,\rho^2 - m^2 \right)}{\rho^2}\,P_{\ell m}
&= 
0.
\end{align*}

*Option 1.*

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\left[ \frac{1}{\rho_0\,\rho} \right]}
\left(
-\frac{d }{d\rho }\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\frac{d}{d\rho }\right]
+ 
 \left[-\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\,\ell^2  \right]
 \right)P_{\ell m}
&= 
-\left[m^2 \right]\,P_{\ell m}
.
\end{align*}
This option works. This is because   $ \left[\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]$, $\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]'$, $\left[-\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\,\ell^2  \right]$, and $\left[ \frac{1}{\rho_0\,\rho} \right]$ are real and continuous, and $\left[ \frac{1}{\rho_0\,\rho} \right]>0$ and $ \left[\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]>0$ on the interval  on the interval $[a,b]$, where $b>a  > 0$.

*Option 2.*

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]}\left(-\frac{d }{d\rho }\left[\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\frac{d  }{d\rho }\right]
+ 
\left[
\frac{  m^2  }{\rho_0\,\rho }\right]
\right)P_{\ell m}(\rho)
&= 
 -\left[-\ell^2\right] P_{\ell m}(\rho)
.
\end{align*}
This option works. This is because   $ \left[\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]$, $\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]'$, $\left[
\frac{  m^2  }{\rho_0\,\rho }\right]$, and $\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0} \right]$ are real and continuous, and $\left[ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0} \right]>0$ and $ \left[\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right]>0$ on the interval  on the interval $[a,b]$, where $b>a  > 0$.

**My Question**

Even though I know from [1] that *Option 2* is considered the correct way to interpret the governing differential equation (so that the eigenvalue is $\pm\ell^2$), I do not understand how come *Option 1* is incorrect as an interpretation. Can you please explain how to resolve this ambiguity?

**Bibliography**

[1] Arfken and Weber, 5th Edition.

[2] Zwillnger, "Handbook of Differential Equations", page 97, 1st Edition.

Comment: When there are two parameters, one of this is usually determined by a previous eigenvalue problem involving one of the parameters, which means those values are not up for grabs, unlike the second parameter. A single eigenvalue problem is not going to determine two different parameters.

Comment: What  I have observed anecdotally is that for $n$ variables, there will generally be $n$ eigenvalue problems along with $n-1$ separation constants. What Disintegrating By Parts says is sensible, but I wonder if there is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the heat equation for $\psi(r,\theta,t)$ on the unit disk centered at the origin.
$$
      \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=c\nabla^2\psi,\;\; 0\le r\le 1,\;0\le\theta\le 2\pi,\;\;t \ge 0.
$$
Using polar coordinates $r,\theta$, the Laplacian may be written as
$$
         \nabla^2\psi = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\theta^2}.
$$
To perform the separation of variables, assume the following form of solution:
$$
          \psi(r,\theta,t)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)T(t).
$$
Plug this into the heat equation and divide the result by $\psi$. Here's what you get:
$$
       \frac{1}{c}\frac{T'}{T}=\frac{1}{rR}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2\Theta}\frac{d^2\Theta}{d\theta^2}
$$
You can separate out the $\theta$ components after multiplying both sides by $r^2$:
$$
     \frac{1}{\Theta}\frac{d^2\Theta}{d\theta^2}=
     \frac{r^2}{c}\frac{T'}{T}-\frac{r}{R}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)
$$
So there is a parameter $m$ such that
$$
      \frac{1}{\Theta}\frac{d^2\Theta}{d\theta^2}=-m^2,
   \;\; -m^2 = \frac{r^2}{c}\frac{T'}{T}-\frac{r}{R}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right).
$$
The parameter $m$ is determined at this point by periodicity in $\theta$ and $\Theta(\theta)=A\cos(m\theta)+B\sin(m\theta)$. Assuming periodicity, $m=0,1,2,3,\cdots$ (negative values of $m$ do not give anything new.) So you don't get to choose the values of $m$ when you're working on a circular disk such as this. The values of $m$ are dictated by the geometry and periodicity in $\theta$.

The final separation of variables is
$$
      \frac{T'}{cT}=\frac{1}{rR}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)-\frac{m^2}{r^2} \\
      \frac{T'}{cT}=\nu,\;\; \nu=\frac{1}{rR}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)-\frac{m^2}{r^2}
$$
The equation in $r$ may be written as
$$
       \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)-\left(\frac{m^2}{r^2}+\nu\right)R=0 \\
       \frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)-\left(\frac{m^2}{r}+\nu r\right)R=0 \\
         r\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+\frac{dR}{dr}-\left(\frac{m^2}{r}+\nu r\right)R=0.
$$
Or, if you don't want $r$ in the denominator,
$$
            r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+r\frac{dR}{dr}-\left(m^2+\nu r^2\right)R=0.
$$
I have an extra negative for the one of the terms, or at least I think I do. Anyway, you get the idea: The parameter $m$ is determined by periodicity; it is not an arbitrary parameter.